# Azure PowerShell return the Name of CustomScriptExtension if it exists

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a variable called `$VMStatus`

```
$VMStatus = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $RGName -VMName $VMName -status
```

Now when I run `$VMStatus.Extensions.Type`, it returns the list of virtual machine extensions for the provided entries.

So now when I run `$VMStatus.Extensions.Type -Match "Custom"`, it returns the entry I am interested in: `Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension`

The problem I am having is getting the `Name` of that `CustomScriptExtension`.  I have tried the following with no success:

```
IF ($VMstatus.Extensions.Type -Match "Custom") {$VMstatus.Extensions.Name}
```

This will actually return ALL entries for `Name` since the first part of the `IF` statement is `TRUE`.

How do I return just the `Name` of the `CustomrScriptExtension` if one exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the following script.

```
##If VirtualMachineExtensionType eq CustomScriptExtension, it means custom script extension install on your VM
$vm=Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $VMName |Where {$_.Extensions.VirtualMachineExtensionType -eq "CustomScriptExtension"}
if ($vm){

    $name = $vm.Extensions|Where {$_.VirtualMachineExtensionType -eq "CustomScriptExtension"} |select Name
    $name
}
```

Comment: I took your suggestion and modified it a bit.  The final line where you show `$name` at the end, I changed to `write-host "Process ended because $name exists."`
But the output is showing 
"Process ended because @{Name=CSE_Name} exists".
How do i get rid of the extra characters in the beginning so it shows just the name itself?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @shengbao-shui-msft for providing the answer above.
I have taken his suggestion and modified it to first look for a CustomScriptExtension, if one exists remove it before continuing on in the runbook

```
$VM = Get-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $VMName | Where-Object {$_.Extensions.VirtualMachineExtensionType -eq "CustomScriptExtension"}
IF ($vm) 
{
    $name = $vm.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.VirtualMachineExtensionType -eq "CustomScriptExtension"} | select-object -ExpandProperty Name
    write-host "Existing CustomScriptExtension found on $VMName as $name . Removing...."

    Remove-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension `
    -VMName $VMName `
    -ResourceGroupName $RGName `
    -Name $name
}
Else 
{
    write-host "There are no CustomScriptExtension found on $VMName . "
}
```